# SQL Server SELECT Where Value Equals Results of Another Select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, postgresql

I want to create a SQL statement to select values from one table based on the values from another. **I would like to know how to do so in SQL, but knowing in PostgreSQL would be nice as well.**

EX:

```
TableA
ID | Label | Value
1    Test    A


TableB
ID | Name | Label
1    TestN  Test
```

I think the query would looks something like this:

```
SELECT Name FROM TableB WHERE Label = SELECT Label FROM TableA WHERE Value = 'A';
```

That one throws errors though. Thoughts?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're close... try this:

```
SELECT Name FROM TableB WHERE Label IN ( SELECT Label FROM TableA WHERE Value = 'A' );
```

EDIT: Started to add the INNER JOIN option but it is listed in another answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you do a INNER JOIN?

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.Name
FROM TableB B
INNER JOIN TableA A ON B.Label = A.Label
WHERE A.Value = 'A'
```

Comment: If Table A has two rows with the same label, this will duplicated the row in Table B

Answer (score 3):

use IN not equals:

```
select Name
from TableB
where Label in ( SELECT Label FROM TableA WHERE Value = 'A' );
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a big fan of "IN" clauses in production code.  others will disagree, I get that.

exists and not exists....

```
SELECT Name FROM TableB tabB WHERE
exists ( select null from TableA innerAAlias WHERE innerAAlias.Value = 'A' /* filter */ and innerAAlias.Label = tabB.Label /* relationship to the outside query */);
```

Answer (score 1):

Using TSQL --> EXISTS...

```
SELECT b.name
FROM Table B AS b
WHERE EXISTS
(SELECT * 
    FROM TableA a
    WHERE b.label = a.label
    AND a.value = 'A');
```